# ZK Wire Components are not accessible in @command Method (MVVM) or viewmodel is not accesible (doAfterCompose MVC)

Tags: java, mvvm, zk

I think i have a fundamental problem with understanding `Wire` components if some one could explain why they work with a `Composer` and the `doAfterCompose()`-Method and why the wiring dosen't work (Component -> NULL) in a `@command`-Method (like onClick from a button).

I can't post the whole code so I'am just pasting parts of a working zul and a working Java Class

I used `MVVM` to access some `values from ZUL-Components`. The `java class` used for this also `generates some components dynamically` with data from a database (`in doAfterCompose()`-Method).

Szenario: the gui shows up and via `doAfterCompose()` several components are created dynamically (Row Component + Checkbox in the Row Component) with the `Wire Component orgTypeRows` (Type Rows). That works fine.

But to acces the results you click on the search button which has the `onClick event "startSearch"` which calls the java method `startSearch()`. In this method I want to access the generated components (Type Checkbox) and verifiy which boxes have been checked but when i try to access the wire component here the Rows Component is NULL

**Here is the ZUL-Code [search.zul](http://pastebin.com/VWiS640i) and the Java-Code [search.java](http://pastebin.com/GR7QGsfV)**

Is this impossible like that? Should i just use a listener for the button in `doAfterCompose()` instead of the `@command` but how can I access the viewmodel in `doAfterCompose()` there all values of the viewmodel are NULL?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you have a fundamental problem with MVC and MVVM.

Let's start with the zul you showed.
I can't find any `apply` attribute in the zul so the controller or viewmodel must be applied in another zul, so I don't know what you are using, MVC or MVVM.
The loading of the properties are the MVVM way.

Let's go now to the java class.
You are mixing 2 completly different things.
First of all extending the `GenericForwardComposer` is an MVC way.
It's even an old one because the `SelectorComposer` is the newest MVC controller where you can annotate the wiring what must be done.

`@Init`, `@Command` => MVVM
`@doAfterCompose`, wiring => MVC

Now you say that the `@Command` method isn't working. Do you mean not triggering?
Don't forget that the MVVM way need's a binder.
Initialisation of a viewmodel :

```
apply="org.zkoss.bind.BindComposer" viewModel="@id('vm') @init('yourPackage.YourClass')"
```

Initialisation of an MVC controller :

```
apply="yourPackage.YourClass"
```

See the difference?
Please, read the documentation about MVC and MVVM on zk website.
Refactor then your whole thing, and if you still have problems come back with a better question where we can help you with.

Comment: Oh sry my bad, I accidentally cut that from the zul -.-. i'am using the `BindComposer and ViewModel` in the `tabpanel`. and the composer `apply` in the `tabbox` the methods both works fine but i can't access the wiring from the `@command` method and in the `doAfterCompose()` i can't access the `ViewModel` object (all values are NULL) but I need both (viewmodel and wiring) to select the viewmodel values and components like checkboxes to see which boxes are checked so that i can prepare a correct HQL-Statement for the database. I have pasted the zul file anew with apply and binding

Comment: I can't reply in the chat because it seems I need 20 reputation for that privilege

Comment: Nope it dosn't work i have the 20 rep now but each time reloading i still get the message you need 20 rep i tried to relog and a different browser but I still get that message

Comment: close and reopen chat?

Comment: I tried that too. I also am trying it on my notebook right now but it dosen't work, maybe there is sync gap between profile and the chat :-/

Comment: on the javascript room the same?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/69383/discussion-between-chillworld-and-user3387852).